# Actionscript 3 remove sound object

Tags: actionscript-3, audio

In my code I define Sound, SoundChannel and URLRequest like below:

```
private var url:String = "MySound.mp3";
private var oSound:Sound;
private var oSoundChannel:SoundChannel;
...
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
this.oSound = new Sound();
this.oSound.load(request);
```

The user can select a new sound and change it. This process (I mean change the sound) can be repeated.
Like below:

```
this.oSoundChannel.stop();
this.url = "deejay.mp3";
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(this.url);
this.oSound = new Sound();
this.oSound.load(request);
this.oSoundChannel = oSound.play();
```

My question (in relation to memory leak / loss):
Is it needed to remove an object (e.g. Sound, SoundChannel or URLRequest)  before loading a new sound-file?
If yes, how can I remove such an element?

```
// E.g. something like: oSound.parent.removeChild(oSound); // <-- It doesn't work properly!
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `oSound=null;` and if you want to use again `if(oSound==null) { oSound=new Sound() }`

Comment: This question is misguided. You don't remove Sound Object from anything. Like EVERY objects in AS3 you qualify them for GC.